# How do I read a text file in java and put some records in another text file and the rest in another text file in java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I want to read a file, that has 2 different department in it, split the lines and put the lines having information technology in a new text file, and those that have bussiness department in another text file. help please. here is what I did to read the file:

```
public class Splitter {
    private static ArrayList<String> lineArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public static class Score { // to close a file
    public void closeFile(Scanner fileToClose) {
        try {
            if (fileToClose != null)
                fileToClose.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("Error closing the files.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static void read() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myFile = new File("D:\\CourseMasterFile.txt"); // find and get
                                                            // the
        // external
        // file information

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile); // open and read the file
                                                    // from
                                                    // the hard disk in to
                                                    // the
                                                    // RAM

        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) { // while there is a line left in
                                            // the
                                            // file

            String sentence = inputFile.nextLine(); // get the one line from
                                                    // the
                                                    // file

            System.out.println(sentence); // print the line in to the consul
            lineArray.add(sentence);

        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell us what is going wrong with your example and then we can help you. We need a **specific** question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to know how to put the file into 2 arrays and put the arrays in two different text files. half of the records in a file and the rest in another. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code ;

```
FileWriter out2 = new FileWriter(file2);
FileWriter out1 = new FileWriter(file1);


 try{
    if(sentence.contains("information technology"))
        out1.write(sentence);
    else
        out2.write(sentence);
    } finally {
        try {
            out1.close();
            out2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```